# Hover effect for images with twitter-bootstrap-3

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

Is there a style that will create a hover effect for images, where when you hover over an image it either fades or shifts color?

Comment: Short answer: No. Long answer: No, but feel free to add your own custom .css for `.hover` effects.

Comment: take a look at http://gudh.github.io/ihover/dist/ for some really cool hover effect for image bootstrap css

Comment: The short answer was confirming what I found.  Thank you for that.  I did find this which is complex and more than I need: http://tympanus.net/Tutorials/OriginalHoverEffects/  This is quite helpful also and I may end up with one of these.  http://designshack.net/articles/css/joshuajohnson-2/

Answer (score 0):

A very basic hover effect:

**html**

```html
<img class="thumbnail" src="...">
```

**css**

```css
.thumbnail {
  opacity: 0.8;
  }
.thumbnail:hover {
  opacity: 1;
  }
```

Comment: Thank you for a real and simple answer to try.